# Re-Downloading all requirments when starting a new kivy project

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

When I'm starting a new kivy project inside my virtualenv, It download again all requirements like SDK, NDK etc...
Help please!!

Answer (score 0):

In a console `cd` to a project directory having the requirement you need need in order tho save the requirements of the (old) project.

```
$ cd /path/to/old/project
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

The `requirements.txt` file will contain a list of the dependencies (with their version) installed.

When create a new project, copy the `requirements.txt` file containing the dependencies you wish to use to your new projects directory.
Now, tell `pip` to install all the dependencies in the `requirements.txt` file.

```
$ cd /path/to/new/project 
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This should install all the dependencies of your old project in the new project.

---

## Ressources

- [Reference Guide : pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/)
- [`$ pip freeze > requirements.txt` considered harmful](https://medium.com/@tomagee/pip-freeze-requirements-txt-considered-harmful-f0bce66cf895)
- [Better Python dependency while packaging your project](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/better-python-dependency-and-package-management-b5d8ea29dff1)

Comment: But it re-download the android-sdk, android-ndk and lot of files!

Comment: Well, yes. That's how it things works when using Python environments. The other solution I see is to not use isolated environments and install the dependencies in your system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using buildozer, it should reuse the sdk and ndk saved in `~/.buildozer/` unless you use different versions in buildozer.spec, if it downloads the same version every time, that's likely a bug. If you use python-for-android directly, you should be able to point it to your already downloaded sdk/ndk directories.